# Why does the program with the following code crash? How to fix that?

Tags: c

I got the following code set up and it actually gets compiled without errors but it crashes all the time I start it. The code is supposed to read and save lines from an .txt file and look for the longest duplicate which it displays. I had some problems with allocating memory since the .txt file is about 127.000 characters long, the problem might have to do with this.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <math.h>
# include <stddef.h>
# include <ctype.h>

    main(){

    printf("test\n");

    FILE *Datei;
    size_t i;
    size_t j;

    Datei = fopen("Eingabe.txt", "r");

    //Zeilen einlesen

    size_t Zeilen_anzahl;
    size_t Zeilen_groesse;
    char **Zeile = NULL;
    char puffer[512];

        while(fgets(puffer, sizeof(puffer), Datei) != NULL) {
            if (Zeilen_anzahl >= Zeilen_groesse) {
                Zeilen_groesse = Zeilen_groesse*2 + 1;
                Zeile = realloc(Zeile, Zeilen_groesse * sizeof(*Zeile)); //Fehlerfall?
            }
        size_t laenge = strlen(puffer);
            if (laenge > 0 && puffer[laenge - 1] == '\n') puffer[--laenge] = '\0';
                laenge++;
                Zeile[Zeilen_anzahl] = malloc(laenge);
                memcpy(Zeile[Zeilen_anzahl], puffer, laenge);
                Zeilen_anzahl++;
            }

    fclose(Datei);

    //Duplikat suchen

    size_t laengste = 0;
    size_t index = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < Zeilen_anzahl; i++) {

            size_t kleinste = strlen(Zeile[i]) + 1;

                if (kleinste <= laengste) continue; //kleiner als längstes Duplikat

                    for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                        if (strcmp(Zeile[i], Zeile[j]) == 0) { //Duplikat gefunden
                            laengste = kleinste;
                            index = i;

                break;      //überspringen
                        }
                    }

        }

        if (laengste > 0) {
            printf("Längstes Duplikat ist: \"%s\".\n");
        }

        else {
            printf("Keine Duplikate gefunden.\n");
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: EDIT: I would love to keep the code this way, since I basically understand what is happening, please don't suggest any other functions to use for better performance. I would love to have a working program before I address this issue at all.

Comment: What error is shown when it crashes?

Comment: Also you don't provide an additional string argument to `printf("Längstes Duplikat ist: \"%s\".\n");`

Comment: No particular error to mention just "Zusatz.exe" stopped working. Thanks for pointing the missing argument out, totally forgot it.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0):

first of all: ALWAYs check the result of open()

then: \n may be two characters (CR/LF), so comparing with '\n' is not apropriate

Answer (score 0):

In addition to some missing error checks I found the following bugs:

```
size_t Zeilen_anzahl = 0;   // Forgot to initialize 
size_t Zeilen_groesse = 1;  // Forgot to initialize 
char **Zeile = NULL;
char puffer[512];
Zeile = malloc(Zeilen_groesse * sizeof(*Zeile)); // I had to add this, not sure why. realloc should work on NULL pointer

    while(fgets(puffer, sizeof(puffer), datei) != NULL) {
        if (Zeilen_anzahl >= Zeilen_groesse - 1) {   // Off by one in size check
```

Comment: Oh I am so thankful! That fixed the problem with the crashes. Even though I don't seem to need "Zeile = malloc(Zeilen_groesse * sizeof(*Zeile));" it shouldn't be required, right?

Comment: I agree, but I ran it and `realloc` seems to work on my machine with `char **Zeile = NULL;`

Comment: The malloc shouldn't be required.